# SQL: How to track point changes in the table

Tags: sql, diff

I have a table where points change daily. I need to track how many points change on daily basis. 
For Eg:

```
    Date         PointsWon
    2018-03-20     4567
    2018-03-19     4513
    2018-03-18     3879
```

What would be an easy way to do this?

Comment: Self join matching date to date minus 1.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use the ANSI-standard `lag()` function:

```
select t.*, (pointswon - lag(pointswon) over (order by date)) as diff
from t;
```

Comment: I tried using lag but because all the dates are not there, lag wont work.

Comment: @Drishti . . . The dates are all there in *this* question.  I might suggest that you accept this answer and ask *another* question with more appropriate data and descriptions.